# How do I rename the helper app that is generated by Electron Builder?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I have an app named **myCalendar**.

How do I rename the helper from **myCalendar Helper.app** to be just **myCalendar**?

[image]

(I know this is a code signing issue and I am fixing the separately)

I have tried looking in [electron-builder config](https://www.electron.build/configuration/mac) and can't find any parameters to change this.